# PHP Custom Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I am learning PHP. I have a large PHP array of item.

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
```

I would like to display 10 cars on a page with pagination (Page 1, Page 2, etc). If there are 101 items in `$cars`, there should be 11 navigational items (with Page 11 only showing one item).

This is a large array so I am not sure the best way to structure this or which PHP functions are best to use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`array_slice()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)** for that. More specifically:

```
$currentPageItems = array_slice($array, $pageYouWant, $howManyItemsYouWant);
```